# Adding 2nd Exchange server for remote users current access too slow

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange

I currently have a single Exchange 2010 setup and many remote office connecting over VPN to it.  The further away users get the slower access is.  We are in CA and have an office in France, they feel the pain the most, even with cached mode it can be very slow.

Exchange is running on 2008 R2 standard, its is a VM with data center licensing on all host.

We will be adding an MPLS connection to this office this year, but I don't know if that will help performance enough.

What is the best thing to do to resolve this issue?  Can I add a Mailbox server at their location, Can I sync public folders with this type of setup?  They still rely on public folders heavy and Cached mode does not help currently with public folders.

Any links, search terms, or info is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your first sentence, these remote users are connecting via VPN.  Does this mean there is no direct connection from the office in France to your main office in CA?  This is important if you plan to implement a second Exchange 2010 Server in the France office as there has to be direct connection of some kind between the two servers.  You will also need to implement a DC / GC in France if there isn't already one there.

Assuming you have a direct link between the two locations, adding another Exchange Server in France is straight forward.  You will need to add the CAS, HT and MBX role in France.  You can also sync Public Folders abetween the two servers.  Just be aware that the first sync may consume a decent amount of traffic and take some time depending on the size of your public folder database.

I assume you will also move the mailboxes of the users homed in France to the France Exchange Server?  I hope so as that would make the most sense.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, there is a Juniper SRX appliance at each site, so the IPSEC VPN tunnel is always on, and there is site to site connectivity.  I should have mentioned, there is a RODC in France as well.  This answer helps a lot, as I can now research the roles you listed.

Comment: Exchange Server 2010 will not interact with a RODC, but requires a writeable DC. I would start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998636(v=exchg.141).aspx for planning and deployment documentation.